# With Jetpack DataStore, is possible to open a already created data store for a name?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I like to know if is possible to open a data store in adittion to create it.

Reading the official documentation, theres the mention about the extension function on Context class for creating a preference data store.

```kotlin
fun Context.createDataStore(name: String): DataStore<Preferences>
```

But, it creates a new data store, is possible to get a previously created one, like the previous implementation of SharedPreferences?

```kotlin
/* getting or creating a shared preferences instance */
context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This was submitted to the [google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170727614).

**(UPDATE)**

After applying the preferences data store, i noticed the following:

> when using preferences data store, the data lives only when the app is opened and active.

I remember one thing that is mandatory when using the shared preferences:

> They (the preferences) are saved until i unistall the app...

this is not happening when using the preferences data store.

I hope they'll fix that, understanding that is in alpha phase.

Comment: Yes, you can similar to SharedPreferences, access **data** property of created DataStore to read its preferencesKey OR directly `edit` in Datastore to update value of preferencesKey.

Comment: when using 'createDataStore', it creates a new data store, with all the previous key=value deleted :(

Comment: Once you create you need to keep reference of it and not to use `createDataStore` again. Use that reference for future `edit` or **read** operation. Refer this example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore/#5

Comment: i did that, but, when i close the app, and later open it, the values i saved before are gone. i edited the question @user8608556

Comment: Preferences are persistent, check again you might be updating it again. I suggest play the same things with codelab sample link that I provided earlier that will help.